# Retrieving merged properties in Spring

Tags: java, spring, property-placeholder

I am trying to get all the merged properties in my projects. Below is the section of my config file for properties.

```
<bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
</bean>

<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:proj-config.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:${proj.env}-pauth-config.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:${proj.env}-pauth-override-config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried with `PropertiesFactoryBean` class also but then my `proj.env` variable is not found. Suggest me how to retrieve all the merged properties in spring at runtime.

Comment: individually like [`@Value( "${jdbc.url}" )`](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/) or how do you mean retrieving all merged properties?

Comment: no, i mean retrieving key-value pairs of all the properties at the runtime. I have seen a method mergeProperties() of PropertiesFactoryBean but not able to access it

Comment: Some properties are overrided based on environment variable, so i need some way to to get all these key-value pairs

Comment: You can get the bean "applicationProperties"

Comment: Can you show me with the code, i have tried but could not get the properties